# Getting Unique Items from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an object GroceryItem which is defined like the following:

```
@interface GroceryItem : NSObject
{

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) int groceryItemId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;


@property (nonatomic,strong) GroceryItemCategory *groceryItemCategory;

@end
```

Now, I need to retrieve all the unique grocery categories out of the groceryItems collection. I am using the following code:

```
 NSSet *uniqueGroceryItemCategories = [NSSet setWithArray:[_groceryItems valueForKey:@"groceryItemCategory.title"]];
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
[<GroceryItem 0x7fea8d82b5a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key groceryItemCategory.title.'
```

title is a property defined in GroceryItemCategory class and it is of type string just like it is defined in the GroceryItem class.

**UPDATE:**

I am just using KeyPath and it seems to be working:

```
 NSArray *array = [_groceryItems valueForKeyPath:@"groceryItemCategory.title"];
```

Comment: You figured it out before I could reply. (Well done.) You should post an answer to your own question, and then except it. That way people know the problem is solved.

Comment: Let me update in few hours! I think I have a problem. I do not think the items returned are unique. I might have to use a NSSet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html).  You should be able to use `@distinctUnionOfObjects`, like this:

```
NSArray *array = [_groceryItems valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.groceryItemCategory.title"];
```